# Reversed operation of `tf.boolean_mask`

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering after `tf.boolean_mask`, how to recover the predicted results as a 2D tensor from `pred` (1D tensor) and `mask` (2D array with elements of 'True' or 'False'), where `False` defaulted as `0`.

```
labels = np.random.rand(256, 256)
heatmaps = np.random.rand(256, 256, 10)

mask = labels > 0.5
heatmaps = tf.boolean_mask(heatmaps, mask)

scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=heatmaps)
pred = tf.argmax(scores, axis=1)
```

By the way, it is easy to implement using `numpy`:

```
pred_reshape = np.zeros((256, 256))
pred_ = sess.run(pred)
pred_reshape[mask] = pred_
```

However, it needs to convert `tensor` back to `numpy` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do the masking after the calculations multiplying the mask. The result would be the same and you would keep the shape (256,256).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

labels = np.random.rand(256,256)
mask = labels > 0.5
heatmaps = np.random.rand(256, 256, 10)

scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=heatmaps)
pred = tf.argmax(scores, axis=2) # Note that now the 10-element axis is 2 (256,256,10)

# Masking
pred_reshape = tf.multiply(pred, mask)
```

The drawback is that unnecessary calculations are made for the data that will be masked.

Note that now `pred_reshape` is an array of `int`, instead of `float`.

As a check:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

labels = np.random.rand(256,256)
mask = labels > 0.5
heatmaps = np.random.rand(256, 256, 10)

sess = tf.Session()

# Original code
original_heatmaps = tf.boolean_mask(heatmaps, mask)
original_scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=original_heatmaps)
original_pred = tf.argmax(original_scores, axis=1)

original_pred_reshape = np.zeros((256,256))
original_pred_ = sess.run(original_pred)
original_pred_reshape[mask] = original_pred_

# New code
new_scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=heatmaps)
new_pred = tf.argmax(new_scores, axis=2)
new_pred_reshape = tf.multiply(new_pred, mask)
new_result = sess.run(new_pred_reshape)

print('All elements equal:', np.all(original_pred_reshape==new_result))
```

Notice that `argmax` returns the index of the highest element, which in some cases is 0. Therefore, you will not be able to differentiate those elements from the masked elements if you need it: both in the first case `pred_reshape = np.zeros (( 256, 256))`, as in the second `pred_reshape = tf.multiply (pred, mask)`.

If you need to differentiate the masked elements, maybe you could do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

labels = np.random.rand(256,256)
mask = labels > 0.5
heatmaps = np.random.rand(256, 256, 10)

scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=heatmaps)
pred = tf.argmax(scores, axis=2) # Note that now the 10-element axis is 2 (256,256,10)

# Masking
pred_reshape = tf.add(pred, 1)
pred_reshape = tf.multiply(pred_reshape, mask)
pred_reshape = tf.add(pred_reshape, -1)
```

And you have the masked elements with `-1` values.